# Are there any VB6 Performance Tools?

Tags: performance, vb6

I'm working on a CPU-bound VB6 application, and I was wondering if there are any performance tools for VB6 along the lines of Performance and Coverage Analyser? Does anyone know of any?

Comment: See also [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/766596/whats-the-best-way-of-timing-functions-measuring-performance-in-vb6) - not an exact duplicate, but interesting

Comment: I don't know if it is still possible to find it, but I long ago used something I think called "Numega DevPartner Studio" (BoundsChecker) with Visual Studio 6.  It had an incredibly usable profiler that I believe worked with VB6.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[VB Watch Profiler](http://www.aivosto.com/vbwatch.html) is supposed to do these things. I haven't used it myself.

Comment: The Aivosto tools are excellent. I used them years back when I was working with VB6. Very much worth the (low) cost. But are they still selling it? I guess so with the link still up...

Comment: thank you for that; it seems to be just what I am looking for. Now it's just a question of persuading the management to fork out for it...

Comment: The free trial version works on projects of up to 10 files.  This might help you create a test case and profile it, then take the results (even as screenshots) to help make a case for what it will do for you.  In some cases you can even pull out suspect modules and wrap them in a small driver program to do enough profiling even using the free version to find problems.

Comment: While installing VBWatch, McAffee reported detection of a trojan it refers to as Artemis!C3BE21A2259F in InstVBWb.exe. Apparently Artemis is the name given to possible threats that haven't been specifically identified as a definite threat.